# Creating QnA Chatbot on Azure

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I need to know if I can create a custom QnA chatbot using Azure Language Studio? I found some tutorials in the web but there are no blogs or anything which shows how can we connect azure SQL to a custom QnA chatbot in Azure Language studio.

The usecase I want from the chatbot:

1. Get input from users.
2. Understand the input using NLP.
3. Find the relevant data in azure SQL database (Which consists large number of tables and is complex).
4. Give correct answer to the user in natural language.

Can any one please let me know if this is possible in azure LUIS and if yes, then I need some guidelines on this.

Looked every where in the internet. Didn't find any solution even on the documentations.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is certainly possible, but you'll want to use the new [Azure Cognitive Service for Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/overview). It is a set of services that replace QnA and LUIS, which have since been deprecated. As for your bot interface itself, you could use Power Virtual Agents or Bot Framework to handle the user interaction and calling external services (these do not need to just be Microsoft services. You can access external endpoints as well).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did read about Cognitive Services but the problem I faced here was for the the knowledgebase, it there is no option to add our azure database. So I am looking how can I link my database to it so it can get data from there

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the only way to do that is to recognize the user's intent using Custom Question Answering/Conversational Language Understanding and then make a request to your external database using recognized intent. If you use Microsoft Bot Framework SDK, you can connect your DB to the project there.
There are a few words about Bot Framework SDK in the [article](https://ruby.mobidev.biz/posts/faq-chatbot/).